# Android Browser Render Chart of SSRS Report as a Broken Image

Tags: charts, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

When I view a SSRS report in Android mobile browser, the **chart within the SSRS report is rendered as a broken image**, while other details, such as table data, can be rendered as usual. **There is no issue when I view the same SSRS report in PC browser.**

I tried to inspect the chart in PC browser and copied the source link of the chart image element, and then opened it in my mobile browser, but the file could not be loaded. The link is something like ***[http://serverA/ReportServer?/Cat1/Reports/Report1&rs:SessionID=xxxx&rs:Format=HTML5&rs:ImageID=xxxx]***. When I change the link to full domain, which is something like ***[http://serverA.abc.mywebsite.com/ReportServer?/Cat1/Reports/Report1&rs:SessionID=xxxx&rs:Format=HTML5&rs:ImageID=xxxx]***, the file could be loaded in my mobile browser and the image can be downloaded.

Therefore, I suspect the cause is the full domain issue. However, the chart is rendered as an image only in browser, but in report builder, it is not an image, isn't it? I am new to SSRS report and report builder, what should I do to solve this issue? Or is there any other possible causes such as the mobile browser does not support the SSRS chart, or something? Any help would be appreciated.